# Refactor a method to put inside the component

Tags: reactjs, methods, ecmascript-6, components, refactoring

I've a method which is currently outside my component class.
How do I refactor it, so that it can be put inside the component class?

Please ignore the other functionalities. 
I just need to put in the refactored myFunction in the 'expected' section.

Could you please help me with this?

### Current:

```
const myFunction = (code, data) => (isValid, availableCodes, defaultValue) => {
  if(isValid) {
    const isAvailableCode = isEmpty(availableCodes) || includes(availableCodes, code);
    return isAvailableCode ? get(data, 'originalQty') : defaultValue;
  } 
  return defaultValue;
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { code , data, minValueAllowed, offersNotAllowed } = this. props;
    const getMinValue = myFunction(code, data);
    const minQty = getMinValue(minValue, offersNotAllowed, 0);
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner
          minQty={minQty}
          data={data}
        />              
      </div>
   );
  }
};
```

### Expected:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {

//refactored myFunction here....
  render() {
    const { code , data, minValueAllowed, offersNotAllowed } = this. props;
    const getMinValue = myFunction(code, data);
    const minQty = getMinValue(minValue, offersNotAllowed, 0);

    return ( 
      <div>
        <Spinner
          minQty={minQty}
          data={data}
        />              
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Does my answer help at all?

Comment: it did....thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Please note the “this” added to myFunction in the render method.

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  myFunction = (code, data) => (isValid, availableCodes, defaultValue) => {
    if(isValid) {
      const isAvailableCode = isEmpty(availableCodes) || includes(availableCodes, code);
      return isAvailableCode ? get(data, 'originalQty') : defaultValue;
    } 
    return defaultValue;
  };

  render() {
    const { code , data, minValueAllowed, offersNotAllowed } = this. props;
    const getMinValue = this.myFunction(code, data);
    const minQty = getMinValue(minValue, offersNotAllowed, 0);
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner
          minQty={minQty}
          data={data}
        />              
      </div>
   );
  }
};
```